# it is possible with request method to calculate all numbers?

Tags: php

In this form, here is my code:

```
 <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $number31=2.000;
    $number32=493;
    $number33=160;
    $number34=333;
    $number35=1.667;
    $number36=1.667;
    $number37=467;
    $number38=133;
    $number39=333;
    $number40=1.333;
    $number41=1.333;
    $number42=440;
    $number43=107;
    $number44=333;
    $number45=1.000;
    $number46=1.000;
    $number47=413;
    $number48=80;
    $number49=333;
    $number50=667;
    $number51=667;
    $number52=387;
    $number53=53;
    $number54=333;
    $number55=333;
    $number56=333;
    $number57=360;
    $number58=27;
    $number59=333;
    $number60=0;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $number31 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number31) {
       case 2.000:
        print "<h2>complete all the table!</h2>";
             echo "<p>2.000, correct|";
             break;
    }

       $number32 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number32) {
       case 493:
             echo "|493, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number33 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number33) {
       case 160:
             echo "|160, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number34 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number34) {
       case 333:
             echo "|333, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number35 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number35) {
       case 1.667:
             echo "|1.667, correct</p>-|";
             break;

    }
    $number36 = test_input($_POST[""]);
    switch ($number36) {
       case 1.667:
             echo "|-<p>1.667, correct|";
             break;


    }

       $number37 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number37) {
       case 467:
             echo "|467, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number38 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number38) {
       case 133:
             echo "|133, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number39 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number39) {
       case 333:
             echo "|333, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number40 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number40) {
       case 1.333:
             echo "|1.333, correct</p>-|";
             break;

    }

    $number41 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number41) {
       case 1.333:
             echo "|-<p>1.333, correct|";
             break;


    }

       $number42 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number42) {
       case 440:
             echo "|440, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number43 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number43) {
       case 107:
             echo "|107, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number44 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number44) {
       case 333:
             echo "|333, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number45 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number45) {
       case 1.000:
             echo "|1.000, correct</p>-|";
             break;

    }
    $number46 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number46) {
       case 1.000:
             echo "|-<p>1.000, correct|";
             break;


    }

       $number47 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number47) {
       case 413:
             echo "|413, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number48 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number48) {
       case 80:
             echo "|80, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number49 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number49) {
       case 333:
             echo "|333, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number50 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number50) {
       case 667:
             echo "|667, correct</p>|";
             break;

    }
    $number51 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number51) {
       case 667:
             echo "|<p>667, correct|";
             break;


    }

       $number52 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number52) {
       case 387:
             echo "|387, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number53 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number53) {
       case 53:
             echo "|53, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number54 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number54) {
       case 333:
             echo "|333, correct|";
             break;   
    }

       $number55 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number55) {
       case 333:
             echo "|333, correct</p>|";
             break; 
    }
    $number56 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number56) {
       case 333:
             echo "|<p>333, correct|";
             break;
    }
       $number57 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number57) {
       case 360:
             echo "|360, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number58 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number58) {
       case 27:
             echo "|27, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number59 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number59) {
       case 333:
             echo "|333, correct|";
             break;

    }

       $number60 = test_input($_POST[""]);

    switch ($number60) {
       case 0:
             echo "|0, correct</p>|";
             break;

    }


    }
    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }

    ?>
```

I try to make a calculation about loan amortization but I encounter two problems: the page does not appear in the browser but only the code, what may cause? is there a code that it can calculate all
$numbers(subtraction, addition, subtraction, multiplication)?
In more detail I have put 30 `$numbers` for each one `case` in order to find out if it is correct, I want to fill in all the numbers, correct to get a confirmation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML as well?

Comment: How are you accessing the file? Is the file extension .PHP and are you accessing it through a web server that has PHP installed and active?

Comment: of course, see here my link: [https://codepen.io/mariapesm/pen/JaGZyE?editors=1010]

Comment: please sorry if I did not put the whole code in the previous comment when you ask me to provide html.

Comment: @Dave yes my file is extension.PHP but it doesn't work on google browser only on Firefox also I notice that I had made a small mistake with the document root but now work fine.

Comment: Is there a way to calculate $numbers?